# Did Harry ever tell anyone else about Snape's memories?

Tags: harry-potter

I guess Hermione and Ron had to know that Snape gave Harry his memories, as they were there. Did Harry (or any of them) tell anyone else that Snape gave him memories to watch (experience?)? And if so, did he tell anyone (even Ron or Hermione) what was in them, what he saw? I'm pretty sure it wasn't mentioned (directly at least) in the book.

I'm sure he made sure that everyone knew that Snape was, in fact, on their side, and probably even that he was highly instrumental in Voldemort's downfall. I'm more wondering whether Harry told anyone how he knew, i.e. through Snape's own memories, and if so, did he reveal anything more specific about what the memories contained?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, he did.

> Happiness would come, Harry thought, but at the moment, it was muffled
>   by exhaustion, and the pain of losing Fred and Lupin and Tonks pierced
>   him like a physical wound every few steps. Most of all, he felt a
>   stupendous relief, and a longing to sleep. But first he owed an
>   explanation to Ron and Hermione, who had stuck with him for so long,
>   and who deserved the truth. **Painstakingly, he recounted what he had
>   seen in the Pensieve**, and what had happened in the forest.

Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Printed in U.S.A first edition, July 2007 hardcover, page 746.

Comment: Yay! Now, which one of the two of you and Slytherincess are each other's alter ego and which is the main personality? :p

Comment: @DVK - I'm not sure if that's a joke or not, but I assure you, I'm not Slytherincess using a different name. I've just read the books a few times.(understatement)

Comment: dead serious. You also kept denying you were JKR

Comment: That's funny!!  Check my Stackoverflow or Christianity.stackexchange.com activity. I've been  S.O. user for years. I just came here for the first time this week because my wife had a question (the first one I posted) How would someone fake a few years of activity?

Comment: I kid, I kid :) You do have very similar MO though (a good one :)

Comment: Man, you had me!. I've seen her answers. She's a lot better than me.

Comment: ... than anyone (on HP stuff at least)

Answer (score 5):

I have **absolutely** no canon backup for this.. But, based on Harry's Character AND based on how he spoke of Snape to his son, later, I cannot imagine that he failed to 'clear the air' about Snape once it was no longer something that could cause harm.

Failing that, he would eventually have to tell his children to explain his comments at the end of Hallows, but I can't imagine the same boy who was so focused on proper credit being given for the winning of the Tri-wizard tournament not giving credit where it was due to a character he knew was terribly misunderstood.

Anyone got any JKR quotes on the subject or anything?  I suspect such clarification would have to come from her.

** Speaking of what he did / did not reveal ** at least some aspects of the memory he revealed, even if he didn't say how he knew; at the end of Hallows:

> “Snape’s Patronus was a doe,” said Harry, “the same as my mother’s, because he loved her for nearly all of his life, from the time when they were children. You should have realized,” he said ...

I suspect he later explained (since he was sure to be asked) how he knew this.. but have no canon evidence.

Comment: I'm sure he made sure that everyone knew that Snape was, in fact, on their side, and probably even that he was highly instrumental in Voldemort's downfall, I'm more wondering whether Harry told anyone *how* he knew, i.e. through his memories, and if so, did he reveal anything more specific about what the memories contained?  I'll add this explicitly to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is in the book... a similar question was ask on a [live chat](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html) in 2007

Not so much on the details of the memories but Harry made sure that the Wizarding World knows Snape involvement. He also made sure Snape's Portrait was reinstated in the Headmaster's office.

Unfortunately Rita Skeeter will publish a biography *"Snape: Scoundrel or Saint?"* along the line of *"The Life and Lies of Albus Dumbledore"*. Given what she did to Dumbledore, certain event in the memories (from the book) will likely be mention in particularly negative light.

Answer (score 0):

Harry Potter told his son, Albus Severus Potter who then blabbed it to his friend, Scorpius Malfoy.

> **SCORPIUS:** *You loved his mother. I don’t remember everything. I know you loved his mother. Harry’s mother. Lily. I know you spent
> years undercover. I know without you the war could never have been
> won. How would I know this if I hadn’t seen the other world . . . ?*
>
> SNAPE says nothing, overwhelmed.
>
> *Only Dumbledore knew, am I right? And when you lost him you must have felt so alone. I know you’re a good man. Harry Potter told his son
> you’re a great man.*
>
> SNAPE looks at SCORPIUS — unsure what’s going on. Is this a trick? He
> is quite seriously at a loss.
>
> **SNAPE:** *Harry Potter is dead.*
>
> **SCORPIUS:** *Not in my world. He said you were the bravest man he’d ever met. He knew, you see — he knew your secret — what you did for
> Dumbledore. And he admired you for it — greatly. And that’s why he
> named his son — my best friend — after you both. Albus Severus
> Potter.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Cursed Child](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29056083-harry-potter-and-the-cursed-child)</sup></sub>

Comment: That was the redeeming dialogue, and by far the most moving part of the book-script.

Answer (score -1):

You must read the books, opposed to simply watching the movies. In the book, in the very next chapter, “Flaw in The Plan”, he is already tell the truth about Snape to everyone in the Great Hall including Voldemort himself.

Comment: -1 the question specifically asks if Harry told anyone of the memories in the Pensieve, not if he told them about Snape being on their side